# Computing the moments of a triangle

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, euclidean-geometry, integration

Assume you have a triangle in the plane defined by its three vertices at $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$, and $(x_2,y_2)$. Is there a general expression for the moments of the triangle, where the moments are defined as averages by the following expression:

$$\langle x^n y^m \rangle = \frac{1}{A}\int_\triangle x^n y^m \, dA $$

Integrating manually to compute the first few moments, one can obtain:

$$\langle x \rangle = \frac{1}{3} \left(x_0+x_1+x_2\right) $$

$$\langle x^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{6} \left(x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_0 x_1+x_0 x_2+x_1 x_2\right) $$

$$\langle x y \rangle = \frac{1}{12}\left(2 x_0 y_0+x_1 y_0+x_2 y_0+x_0 y_1+2 x_1 y_1+x_2 y_1+x_0 y_2+x_1 y_2+2 x_2 y_2 \right)$$

Is it possible to obtain a closed form expression for general $n$ and $m$ using combinations of the coordinates?

**EDIT:**

Can the same be done for line segments defined by their endpoints $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$?
Again the first few moments in this case are:

$$\langle x \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left(x_0+x_1\right) $$
$$ \langle x^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{3} \left(x_0^2+x_0 x_1+x_1^2\right) $$
$$ \langle x^3 \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \left(x_0^3+x_0^2 x_1+x_0 x_1^2+x_1^3\right) $$
$$ \langle x y \rangle = \frac{1}{6} \left(2 x_0 y_0+x_1 y_0+x_0 y_1+2 x_1 y_1\right) $$
$$ \langle x^2 y \rangle  = \frac{1}{12} \left( 3 x_0^2 y_0+2 x_0 x_1 y_0+x_1^2 y_0+x_0^2 y_1+2 x_0 x_1 y_1+3 x_1^2 y_1\right)$$

Comment: Note that the formula for the area of a triangle, given the three coordinates, is $\frac12\begin{vmatrix}x_0&y_0&1\\\\x_1&y_1&1\\\\x_2&y_2&1\end{vmatrix}$

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0031-3203(95)00147-6 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02020802 might also be useful.

Comment: The final integral I settled with is $\int_0^1\int_0^1 2u\left((1-u)x_0+u\left((1-v)x_1+vx_2\right)\right)^p\left((1-u)y_0+u\left((1-v)y_1+vy_2\right)\right)^q\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}u$ which evaluates to a hypergeometric mess in *Mathematica*; I doubt you'd want that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using [Green's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem).

[image: Green's Theorem Image from wikipedia]

Refer my earlier answer here for more details: [Why doesn't a simple mean give the position of a centroid in a polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/why-doesnt-a-simple-mean-give-the-position-of-a-centroid-in-a-polygon/3182#3182)

Comment: The second link is not working..

Comment: @iamjackbauer: Thanks! I have removed the link.

Comment: right! but do you know if i can find a copy of that file somewhere or if you have one, i ll be glad to take it.

Comment: @iamjackbauer: Unfortunately, no, I don't have a copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a quadruple sum as a closed form (it was the best simplification of the integral I gave in the comments that I could manage, using repeated applications of the binomial theorem), then

$\langle x^p y^q\rangle=\displaystyle 2\sum_{k=0}^p\sum_{\ell=0}^q \frac{(-1)^{k+\ell}\binom{p}{k}\binom{q}{\ell}\nu_{k\ell}}{k+\ell+2} x_0^{p-k} y_0^{q-\ell}$

where

$\displaystyle \nu_{k\ell}=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^\ell \frac{\binom{k}{i}\binom{\ell}{j}}{k-i+\ell-j+1}\left(x_0-x_1\right)^i \left(x_1-x_2\right)^{k-i} \left(y_0-y_1\right)^j \left(y_1-y_2\right)^{\ell-j}$

is an explicit expression for $\langle x^p y^q\rangle$.

FWIW, *Mathematica* is unable to evaluate this (as usual with such complicated multiple sums).

---

For the problem of finding the moments of a line segment with endpoints $\left(x_0, y_0\right)$ and $\left(x_1, y_1\right)$, the integral can be derived by noting that a set of parametric equations for the line passing through the two given points is

$\displaystyle \begin{align*}x&=x_0+t(x_1-x_0)\\y&=y_0+t(y_1-y_0)\end{align*}\qquad 0\leq t\leq1$

Substituting the two equations into the expression $x^p y^q$ and integrating over the parameter range gives

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\left(x_0+t\left(x_1-x_0\right)\right)^p\left(y_0+t\left(y_1-y_0\right)\right)^q\mathrm{d}t$

which can be expanded into a double sum (again by using the binomial theorem):

$\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^p\sum_{k=0}^q\frac{\binom{p}{j} \binom{q}{k}}{j+k+1}\left(x_1-x_0\right)^j \left(y_1-y_0\right)^k x_0^{p-j} y_0^{q-k}$

which can be "simplified" into the [Appell hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html):

$x_0^p y_0^q F_1\left(1;-p,-q;2;1-\frac{x_1}{x_0},1-\frac{y_1}{y_0}\right)$