# How can I calculate the centroid of polygon?

Tags: geometry, mathematica

What is the way to calculate the centroid of polygon? I have a concave polygon of 16 points, and I want know the centroid of that.

thanks

Comment: You've seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon)?

Comment: As for a *Mathematica* routine: `PolygonCentroid[pts_?MatrixQ] := With[{dif = Map[Det, Partition[pts, 2, 1]]}, ((ListConvolve[{1, 1}, #] & /@ Transpose[pts]).dif)/(3 Total[dif])]`. Maybe somebody can do better than me...

Comment: thanks but i will be delighted if u could a bit explain me thx

Comment: Explain what? The formula? The code? You're a bit vague...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**I. CONSIDERATIONS.**
(In 2 parts.  The formulas are at the end of each.)

**Case: Point List**

I have sixteen marbles of equal mass.  Let us agree they all lie in one plane.

**Q1:** What is the center of mass of the set of marbles?

The center of mass of a sphere is its center.  So let the coordinates of the marble centers be:

$\;\;\;\;\;Pts = A_1, A_2.... A_{16}. $

To find the centroid C, average them:

$(1)\;\;\;\;\;C =(A_1+A_2+....+A_{16})/16.  $

---

**Case: Polygon**

Now, using (**Pts**) as the vertices, I cut out a 16-sided polygon, **Jerome**.

**Q2:** What is the center of mass of Jerome?

*This is not the same question.*  How can I ask it correctly? Consider (1) above.  What has changed? I see two problems:

1. There are many concave polygons through 16 given points.  Which did I cut out? I must uniquely identify the region (area) I want to measure. Here are two ways:

   a) Break up Jerome into distinct, convex regions. If a set of points
   are the vertices of a convex polygon, that polygon is unique. Each
   convex region of Jerome is uniquely determined by its vertices.

   b) Arrange **Pts** so that the order (A1 -> A2 -> A3 .... ->An) follows the perimeter in a single direction, without leaps or self-intersections.  A unique perimeter is a unique polygon.

   Both ways allow me to draw the figure.  Note that the simple average (mean) does not distinguish order; it can't give the correct answer.
2. Jerome is a plane figure:  Its mass is proportional to area.  But "the mean of coordinates" is not the same thing as "proportional to area".  Area *of what*? Again, the mean can't, in general, give an answer.

I now have a unique definition of the task.  I have also discarded the simple average where it can't apply, without knowing the answer or doing any math. Going a bit further, it seems that the mean could be right if the vertices are equally distributed about a common center (this hunch turns out to be correct; e.g. regular polygons).

Now to solve the problem...

(A correct formula is given here: [Why doesn't a simple mean give the position of a centroid in a polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/why-doesnt-a-simple-mean-give-the-position-of-a-centroid-in-a-polygon) , but I want to know how to obtain that formula.)

Answer (score 10):

**II.  SOLVE THE PROBLEM**

[Why doesn't a simple mean give the position of a centroid in a polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/why-doesnt-a-simple-mean-give-the-position-of-a-centroid-in-a-polygon) leads to formulas.

Frown.  I want to know how to *set up and solve the problem*. A solution can always be converted to a formula. The reverse --figuring out how a problem was solved by looking at the formula-- is very hard.  So I will solve problem from scratch.

A working demonstration of the method below [can be found here](http://www.geogebratube.org/material/show/id/93239).  The linked document is a Geogebra worksheet; feel free to download it, examine the code, and use it as you see fit.

**A. Observation**
The centroid of triangle $\Delta ABC$ is the simple average of its vertices:
$\;\;\;D = (A+ B + C)/3$.  
**What?** Point order does not matter here: take the vertices A,B,C, in any order, they are the same triangle.  To prove the formula is correct, I might Integrate the triangle area; Find the balance point of figure ABC; or, with compass and straightedge, draw the intersection of the medians.  I say, the point is the same in every case.

**B. Procedure**
I will convert the problem into one I know how to solve:
*Proposition:* Find the centroid of a set of weighted points.

1. Chop Jerome up into mutually exclusive triangles.
2. Say there are *m* triangles. For each triangle $\;\Delta_k, \;k =1, 2, \ldots, m,\;$ find the centroid $C_k$, and the area (weight) $w_k$.  The set of weighted points is then $[\frac{w_k C_k}{J}],$ where J is the area of Jerome.
3. *Solution*:  Add 'em up.
   I say, the resulting point is the centroid of the polygon.

**I have a general solution** (I can always carry out this procedure). But it's messy: I don't have a triangulation rule. *Now what?* A good way to generalize is to start with a case I can solve.

**C. Case: Jerome is Convex** 
It is commonly known that, given a convex polygon $P$, we may choose any vertex, $V,$ draw segments from $V$ to every non-adjacent vertex, and $P$ is correctly triangulated.

I will also use the following formulas:
 -Let any two sides of $\Delta ABC$ be vectors ${\rm  u =(u_1, u_2),\;\; v= (v_1, v_2)}.\;$  Then
 $\;\;\;{\rm Area}_{\Delta ABC} = \tfrac{1}{2}|{\rm  u \times  v}|,\;\;\;\;\;$where (the determinant) ${\rm u \times v}={\rm u_1 v_2-u_2 v_1}$.

-Let sides $AB, AC$ of $\Delta ABC$ be vectors ${\rm  u, v}.\;$  Then the centroid D= (A+B+C)/3 can be written
 $\;\;\;D = A + \tfrac{1}{3}|{\rm  u +  v}|.$

I have gathered what I need.

**D. Solution**

1. Let the counterclockwise path of my *n*-gon be given, in order, by
   $\;\;[A_i] = A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ 
   For covenience, I choose $V=A_1$.
2. Draw the *n-1* vectors from A_1 to the other vertices:
   $\;\;[{\rm a_i}] = (A_{k+1}-A_1),\;\; k = 1, 2, \ldots n\!-\!1$
3. I have *n-2* adjacent triangles with centroids
   $\;\;[C_i] = A_1 + \tfrac{1}{3}{\rm (a_k+a_{k+1})},\;\; k = 1, 2, \ldots n\!-\!2$
   And areas (weights)
   $\;\;[w_i] = \tfrac{1}{2}{\rm (a_k\times a_{k+1})},\;\; k = 1, 2, \ldots n\!-\!2$
   (I dropped the absolute value: counter-clockwise, ${\rm u \times v}$ is positive.) Then
   Total area = $\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} w_k$ and
4. The centroid $C_J$  of Jerome is the sum of weighted triangle 'roids, divided by total area:
   $\;\;C_J= {\large \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} w_k C_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} w_k}}$,

which can be written

$$(2)\;\;C_J= A_1+{\large \frac{1}{3} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} ({\rm a_k+ a_{k+1}})({\rm a_k \times  a_{k+1}})}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} ({\rm a_k \times  a_{k+1}})}
}$$

I say, that this is in fact the complete solution: the determinants give *signed* areas: +/- according as the direction of rotation from $A_k$ to $A_{k+1}$, about $A_1$ is positive or negative, preserving measure in either case.

*Being the thing to be done.*